Is there a way to append a custom Astro component to the dom while running?
I'm new to Astro and I'm looking for a way to add new elements to the DOM while execution. I mean, imagine you have a custom Astro Component called "A", a container and a button. So, is there a way for making that every time you press the button, a new element of type A is “added” to the container?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You might be able to do this with Astro components but I think it would be quite complex. Astro components are more convenient for code that should only run on the server. Since you want something to happen on a button click, that will require client-side code.
I would recommend using React, Vue or other library for such a use case instead.
Add React or other lib to your Astro project npx astro add react.
Example of a similar component:
A.jsx
import B from "./B"
import { useState } from "react"

export default function A() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(p => p + 1)}>click me</button>
      <div>
        {[...Array(count)].map(() => <B />)}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

Then use it with client:load or client:only="react" which will make the code run on the server on a page.
index.astro
<A  client:load />

